# VSCode Minify and upload to server automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a web project with several html and js files. I use the minify plugin and get .min versions for each file. I then upload the .min files to the server, but then I have to rename them on the server, to remove the .min extension...

Is it possible to create a task (or whatever) to rename the minified files to its original name and upload the minified version to the server?

For example, my project is

```
index.html
script/page1.js
style/style.css
```

When I minify, I get on my local computer:

```
index.html
index.min.html
script/page1.js
script/page1.min.js
style/style.css
style/style.min.css*
```

I want to upload to the server the minified versions, but with the original names:

```
index.html (but the minified version)
script/page1.js (but the minified version)
style/style.css (but the minified version)*
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to have two files in the same location (e.g. `/styles/main.css`) with different contents depending on the server?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: So yes, you want that. Well, you obviously need to write a script in your favourite tool (bash, Node, python...) and that's too broad for a question. But I wonder what's the point of such a strange process—I don't think nobody else is handling assets that way.